# parameter passing to split function from if condition

Tags: python

```
string= "im fine.gds how are you"

if '.gds' or '.cdl' in string :

    a=string.split("????????")
```

the above string may contain `.gds` or `.cdl` extension. I want to split the string based on the extension.

here how the parameters can be passed to split function.(**EX** if `.gds` is present in string then it should take as `split(".gds")`
if `.cdl` is there in string then it should get `split(".cdl")`)

Comment: That `in` syntax won't work for starters.

Comment: What do you want to do if BOTH ".gds" and ".cdl" are in the string? Split on both? On neither? On just one of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regular expression module `re` to split either by `pattern1` or `pattern2`

```
import re
re.split('\.gds|\.cdl', your_string)
```

Example:

```
>>> re.split('\.gds|\.cdl', "im fine.gds how are you")
['im fine', ' how are you']
>>> re.split('\.gds|\.cdl', "im fine.cdl how are you")
['im fine', ' how are you']
>>> re.split('\.gds|\.cdl', "im fine.cdl how are.gds you")
['im fine', ' how are', ' you']
```

Comment: Nice solution. In general I try to avoid regexes for these simple issues, but if instead of 2 patterns you have 10 this is a good idea.

Comment: And you can even keep the extensions as an iterable:  `ext = ['gds','cdl']` and then:  `'|'.join(re.escape('.'+e) for e in ext)`

Comment: @HerrKaputt, yeah i also try to avoid regexp. In this case one advantage it has, if you have more than one pattern occurs in string, re.split will split on all matches. To do something similar in str.split, you have to call str.split iteratively on result.

Comment: @Vikas, you are right. From the OP I immediately assumed that at most one of the patterns will be present, but it is not clear, which is why I updated my answer with a pointer to yours (and upvoted it too) :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you have to split the `if` statements:

```
if '.gds' in string:
    a = string.split('.gds')
elif '.cdl' in string:
    a = string.split('.cdl')
else:
    a = string # this is a fallback in case none of the patterns is in the string
```

Furthermore, your `in` statement is incorrect; it should have been

```
if '.gds' in string or '.cdl' in string:
```

Note that this solution assumes that only one of the patterns will be in the string. If both patterns can occur on the same string, see Vikas's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to define a function like:

```
def split_on_extensions(string, *extensions):
    for ext in extensions:
        if ext in string:
            return string.split(ext)
    return string
```

Of course, the order in which you give the extensions is critical, as you'll split on the first one...

Answer (score 0):

Are you guaranteed that one of the two of them will be there?

```
a = next( string.split(v) for v in ('.gds','.cdl') if v in string )
```

If you're not positive it will be there, you can catch the `StopIteration` that is raised in `next`:

```
try:
    a = next( string.split(v) for v in ('.gds','.cdl') if v in string )
except StopIteration:
    a = string #????
```

Answer (score 0):

The tags is captured into the first backreference. The question mark in the `regex` makes the star lazy, to make sure it stops before the first closing tag, rather than before the last, like a greedy star would do.

This regex will not properly match tags nested inside themselves, like in `<TAG>one<TAG>two</TAG>one</TAG>`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the BIF [str.partition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html). This is how it works:

```
sring= "im fine.gds how are you"
three_parts_of_sring = sring.partition('.gds')
>>> three_parts_of_sring
('im fine', '.gds', ' how are you')
```

Put it into a little function and your set.

Comment: I don't like this solution -- it gives you the same answer as using `split` as the OP suggests, with additional overhead to remove the `'.gds'` part from the result (you have to transform the tuple to a list, detect where `'.gds'` is, pop it out, etc).

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily use it either, just wanted to point out that there is another option - as stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can iter separators:

```
string= "im fine.gds how are you"
separators = ['.gds', '.cdl']
for separator in separators:
    if separator in string:
        a = string.split(separator)
        break
else:
    a = []
```

Comment: just avoid using the name 'string' because it may be confused with standard (and deprecated) python module 'string'